# Post Thumbinals in different size

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The first theme that I had on my blog I modified to ensure images size 115x171.

I changed this

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
# Post Thumbinals
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ){
    add_image_size( 'tie-small', 70, 70, true );
    add_image_size( 'tie-large', 300, 160, true );
    add_image_size( 'slider', 620, 330, true );
```

into this

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
# Post Thumbinals
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ){
    add_image_size( 'tie-small', 300, 100, true );
    add_image_size( 'tie-large', 400, 150, true );
    add_image_size( 'slider', 900, 300, true );
```

and into Dashboard-Settings-Media-Thumbnail sizes Width 115 Height 171

The problem occurred after updating themes, pictures are sized Width 214 Height 150, although I set up everything as in the previous version of the themes.

What should be changed that instead of 214x150 shows 115x171?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not with the theme. From wordpress codex: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

```
Registers a new image size. This means WordPress will create a copy of the image with the specified dimensions when a new image is uploaded
```

That means, it'll work WHEN UPLOADING NEW IMAGES, not with previous ones.

That the reason you change the theme and nothing changes in uploaded ones.

If you wanted to change the size of old ones, you would have to:

- Create a PHP script to recrop all the old photos.
- Force with CSS the classes to show the photos with that sizes.

### UPDATE:

In http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Resources, you may find plugins to achieve the AJAX recrop of the photos. @MSTannu suggests http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild. Enjoy the coding!

Comment: He wouldn't have to create that script himself, there are many plugins that regenerate thumbnails.

Comment: @MSTannu That would be cool. I only posted what he had to do, if there exists plugins for that, if you  suggest any, I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I've used a couple and stuck with this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
In the folder uploads have the desired size 115x171 of all. Does that mean that I will again have to make the same size (115x171)? 
Is it enough just to edit the theme-functions.php and run AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild?
I'm new at this :(

Comment: AFAIK, it should be enough changing the theme and rebuilding the thumbnails. At least, this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Resources says so.